# Above-the-ground pool slope pressure calculation

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, water

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this "homework" question, but I have a real life problem that requires calculation and I do not have the math knowledge to make them myself.

I have bought an above-the-ground pool, with dimensions of 2x4 meters and water level of 1 meter. The image below describes exactly the model I have.

[image]

The only place I have to install it has a slope that will result in a 10cm difference in water level. The difference is between the narrow side of the pool. In other words if I will fill the pool with 1 meter water level, on one 2 meter side the water will be 1 meter high and the other side it will be 0.9 meter high.

From my understanding this difference will create more pressure on the wall with the higher water level.

My question is, what water level should I achieve on the higher end so that the pressure on this wall would be as it would have to be if the pool would be on a flat surface with 1 meter water level

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Dig the ground out so that the pool is level.

Comment: 8 m3 of water is 8 tonnes. On a 10cm over 200cm slope, that’s a sideways force of 4000 N trying to roll the pool sideways. Will rise side brackets be able to stably resist that? I agree with @MaxW, you should dig out a flat spot.

Comment: I agree that ideally I should dig to make the pool level. Unfortunately I already made a mistake and filled it with water. So what I'm trying to understand is can I somehow compensate the the pressure by filling less water. 
After this hot season I would empty the pool anyway and level the ground.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The pressure on any part of the wall is solely dependent on the depth of the water ***at that point***.

Yes, the force on the "deep-end" wall **will** be greater.  **Greater than the force on the shallow end wall.**

But if you keep the deep-end wall filled to the same $1$ metre depth, there will be exactly the same pressure at each point on the wall, no matter what happens in the rest of the pool.

Comment: Taking your answer into account I would guess that it's fine to leave it at that, but for some reason the manufacturer and everyone else keeps saying that it's very dangerous (and I agree).
My idea was to calculate how much less water I need to fill so it would be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Dimkin- I agree with your concern and have a similar situation. The problem isn't the pressure on the deeper end (which is actually the designed depth) but the LACK of horizontal pressure on the less deep end. This causes the deep end to force the top support ring outward while pulling the less deep end inward creating unequalized support which could force the wall to collapse towards the deep end.